# ImageMagick convert can't convert to webp

Tags: convert, imagemagick, webp

On Ubuntu 12.04 ImageMagick doesn't seem to support webp.

```
convert flyer.png flyer.webp
```

Creates a png file with webp extension.

On [webp docs](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/docs/using) is stated that ImageMagick does support webp

```
$ convert --version`
Version: ImageMagick 6.6.9-7 2012-08-17 Q16
```

I have these both installed:

- `libwebp-dev` - Lossy compression of digital photographic images.
- `libwebp2` - Lossy compression of digital photographic images.

Also, convert can't decode a webp file.

What's wrong, and is this an Ubuntu bug?

Comment: You can list supported formats with `convert -list format`. On my system, with the same `convert` version, *webp* doesn't appear.

Comment: Thx, I created a bugreport on Launchpad. Then it can be fixed for us all. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/imagemagick/+bug/1117481

Comment: This also affects debian 7 (wheezy), but they don't use launchpad for bugs.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

### Fixed in 16.04

In 16.04 `convert flyer.png flyer.webp` does work, although `webp` is needed:

```
sudo apt-get install webp
```

Without `webp` installed, this error message will show:

```
convert: delegate failed `"cwebp" -quiet -q %Q "%i" -o "%o"' @ error/delegate.c/InvokeDelegate/1310.
```

Comment: Unfortunately `webp` is not recognizable by ImageMagick `7.0.8-27` as a delegate, instead you have to install `libwebp-dev`

Comment: Thanks for this. Worked a treat on ImageMagick 6.9.10-14.

Answer (score 23):

The Ubuntu source package for imagemagick does not declare a build dependency on libwebp-dev. Thus imagemagick gets built without webp support. This could be considered a bug in Ubuntu.

Relevant output from the build process:

```
checking for WEBP... 
checking webp/decode.h usability... no
checking webp/decode.h presence... no
checking for webp/decode.h... no
checking for WebPDecodeRGB in -lwebp... no
checking if WEBP package is complete... no
```

And when libwebp-dev is installed:

```
checking for WEBP... 
checking webp/decode.h usability... yes
checking webp/decode.h presence... yes
checking for webp/decode.h... yes
checking for WebPDecodeRGB in -lwebp... yes
checking if WEBP package is complete... yes
```

If you want to fix this just for yourself, you can rebuild the package and install your version:

```
cd /tmp
mkdir imagemagick
cd imagemagick
sudo apt-get build-dep imagemagick
sudo apt-get install libwebp-dev devscripts
apt-get source imagemagick
cd imagemagick-*
debuild -uc -us
sudo dpkg -i ../*magick*.deb
```

Comment: @Janghou It is in Ubuntu bug list now. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/imagemagick/+bug/1117481

Answer (score 20):

In the mean time one can install:

```
$ sudo apt-get install webp
```

And use `dwebp` and `cwebp` commands to decompress/compress from/to webp file format.

Comment: This also allows imagemagick's idenfity to work properly with webp images. It fixes the following errors:

    identify: delegate failed `"dwebp" -pam "%i" -o "%o"' @ error/delegate.c/InvokeDelegate/1310.
    identify: unable to open image `/tmp/magick-510118LyrHZ5A5Sr': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2712.
    identify: unable to open file `/tmp/magick-510118LyrHZ5A5Sr': No such file or directory @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/540.

Comment: Unfortunately `webp` is not recognizable by ImageMagick `7.0.8-27` as a delegate, instead you have to install `libwebp-dev`

Answer (score 3):

WebP support also has some issues with transparency before 6.8.3, so I've used 6.8.9-9 from 15.04 Vivid, and backported it to 14.04 Trusty with webp support. Use at your own risk:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jamedjo/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install imagemagick libmagickcore-6.q16-2
```

---

In case you wish to repeat this, the steps were:

- Using
  `backportpackage imagemagick --source vivid --destination trusty --workdir=imagemagick-backport` to fetch vivid's version and `tar -xf` to extract the `.deb`.
- Then within `debian/control` replacing `dpkg-dev (>= 1.17.6)` dependency, adding dependencies for `libwebp-dev` and replacing `Architecture: any`  with `amd64` to avoid build failures.
- Adding `--with-webp` in `debian/rules`, adding a changelog entry with `dch` and using `debuild -S -sd` to build a source only package.
- Finally, set up an account on launchpad and [follow their instructions](https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA/BuildingASourcePackage) to share your fix.