# What's the meaning of `-uc -us` options in `debuild -uc -us`?

Tags: debuild

Everybody on the Internet tells to build packages with `debuild -uc -us`, [this answer for example](https://askubuntu.com/a/251954), but I totally can't find what do these options mean, even the built-in help (`debuild --help`) doesn't tell anything about `-uc` and `-us`.

So what do these options mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Commands' built in 'help' is usually insufficient for this kind of thing.

If you had read the [`debuild` manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/debuild.1.html) you'd find those are `dpkg-buildpackage` flags which are passed from `debuild` to `dpkg-buildpackage` and then would have been able to use [`dpkg-buildpackage`'s manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/dpkg-buildpackage.1.html) to find the answer.

From the Xenial [man page for `dpkg-buildpackage`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/debuild.1.html):

```
   -us    Do not sign the source package.

   -uc    Do not sign the .changes file.
```

Comment: > "those are dpkg-buildpackage flags which are passed from debuild to dpkg-buildpackage" — this was nowhere near obvious, although I tried reading man page as well. Thank you for the answer!

Comment: @SargeBorsch Read the "Examples" section of the manpage, it says it right here: "dpkg-buildpackage(1) options may be given on the command line."  And provides examples with `-uc -us`.