# How to add WebP support to Eye of GNOME?

Tags: eog, webp

[WebP](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp) image files are [becoming more and more common on the web](https://w3techs.com/technologies/details/im-webp). Eye of GNOME (`eog`) [doesn't support it out-of-the-box](https://help.gnome.org/users/eog/stable/formats-view.html.en). [Some browsers do](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/faq#which_web_browsers_natively_support_webp), and [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/) as well by just [installing the `webp` package](https://askubuntu.com/a/788917/349837) ([`magick`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61208844/4970442)/`convert -list format`).

A [simple search](https://askubuntu.com/a/982955/349837) leads to [webp-pixbuf-loader](https://github.com/aruiz/webp-pixbuf-loader), but might be not that easy for beginners to find and follow that instructions.

How can I add WebP support to Eye of GNOME?

#### References

- Old issue on Bugzilla: [Bug 700751 – Support of images in format "WebP" in EOG](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=700751).
- Newer issue on GitLab: [Cannot open WebP file](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/eog/-/issues/45#note_838080).

  > eog uses GDK-PixBuf, which does not provide support for most formats itself (due to maintainability), but instead has support for formats added by the libraries that actually implement the image format. Currently libwebp, the library in question, does not provide any loader for GDK-PixBuf, but the linked repository (https://github.com/aruiz/webp-pixbuf-loader) provides one.
- Downstream on Launchpad on [gdk-pixbuf](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gdk-pixbuf/+bug/1864215) (duplicated on [libwebp](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libwebp/+bug/1886272)) and [eog](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/eog/+bug/1318327).
- On Debian

  - [David Heidelberg / webp-pixbuf-loader · GitLab](https://salsa.debian.org/okias-guest/webp-pixbuf-loader).
  - [#907306 - configure: error: gdk-pixbuf-query-loaders not found in path - Debian Bug report logs](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=907306).

Answer (score 22):

**2023-12-01 Update**: [added built-in WebP support to GNOME Platform/SDK](https://floss.social/@sonny/111505420648908207).

**2023-10-11 Update**: There is a huge vulnerability on libwebp, CVE-2023-4863:

- https://www.magnetforensics.com/blog/how-to-detect-blastpass-inside-a-webp-file/
- https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/CVE-2023-4863
- https://ubuntu.com/security/CVE-2023-4863

---

### For Ubuntu 22.04

```
sudo apt install webp-pixbuf-loader
```

### For Ubuntu 20.04

Follow these steps to add support for WebP to Eye of GNOME:

1. Prebuild

   ```sh
   sudo apt install git meson ninja-build
   cd /tmp/
   git clone https://github.com/aruiz/webp-pixbuf-loader
   cd webp-pixbuf-loader/
   sudo ln -s /usr/lib/*/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/gdk-pixbuf-query-loaders /usr/bin/gdk-pixbuf-query-loaders  # https://github.com/aruiz/webp-pixbuf-loader/issues/9#issuecomment-537437407
   ```
2. Build on Debian/Ubuntu

   ```sh
   meson builddir -Dgdk_pixbuf_query_loaders_path=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/gdk-pixbuf-query-loaders
   ninja -C builddir
   ```
3. Install

   ```sh
   sudo ninja -C builddir install
   ```

#### Test

```sh
wget -O /tmp/samplefile.webp "https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.sm.webp"
eog /tmp/samplefile.webp
```

### Default app for .webp extension (*image/webp* internet media type)

From EOG issue *[eog.desktop doesn't include webp mimetype](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/eog/-/issues/197)*:

> After installing https://github.com/aruiz/webp-pixbuf-loader eog loads webp images properly... but it is still not added as supported mime type to the .desktop file and, as a consequence, is not offered by default to open those images

To fix this:

```sh
# Get info                                        
#   If you didn't go through above steps:
wget -O /tmp/samplefile.webp "https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.sm.webp"
xdg-mime query filetype /tmp/samplefile.webp      # MIME type of the file: image/webp
xdg-mime query default image/webp                 # .desktop filename of the application which is registered

# Set open .webp with eog
xdg-mime default org.gnome.eog.desktop image/webp # Ask the desktop environment to make application the default
                                                  # application for opening files of type mimetype: Search on
                                                  # ~/.local/share/applications/ (user-wide) or /usr/share/applications/ (system-wide).
sudo update-mime-database /usr/share/mime         # Apply system-wide

# Test
xdg-open /tmp/samplefile.webp
```

Of course, change `org.gnome.eog.desktop` to whatever you want.

### bash-completion

To enable bash-completion support for .webp we should edit  `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/eog` (tested on 22.04 and 24.04), manually  (`_filedir '@(webp|ani|?`) or just:

```
sudo sed -i 's/_filedir '\''@(/_filedir '\''@(webp|/' /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/eog && . /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/eog; grep webp /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/eog
```

---

Ubuntu 22.10 ship WebP support out-of-the-box<sup>[[1](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/webp-pixbuf-loader/+bug/1979121)]</sup>. For 22.04 [you can use a PPA](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2022/08/install-webp-image-support-ubuntu-22-04) (if you trust the developer).

### See also

- [Cannot open 90% of recently saved images (webp format)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1232571/cannot-open-90-of-recently-saved-images/1306737#1306737)
- [Which image-viewers in Linux support the `webp` image format?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/544254/which-image-viewers-in-linux-support-the-webp-image-format?answertab=active#tab-top)
- [URL protocol handlers in basic Ubuntu Desktop](https://askubuntu.com/a/1023143/349837)
- The [promissing](https://chipsandcheese.com/2021/02/28/modern-data-compression-in-2021-part-2-the-battle-to-dethrone-jpeg-with-jpeg-xl-avif-and-webp/) format [JPEG-XL/JXL](https://jpeg.org/jpegxl/) is supported by ImageMagick's [jpeg-xl](https://github.com/ImageMagick/jpeg-xl/blob/main/doc/software_support.md)
- [Loupe](https://gitlab.gnome.org/Incubator/loupe), [probably](https://thisweek.gnome.org/posts/2023/04/twig-92/) the EOG replacement.

Comment: I can't believe that there still isn't a `.deb` package with this that one can just install, without the need to build it from source.

Comment: `meson` failed to build until I installed `libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev libwebp-dev` (Ubuntu 20.04).

Comment: it seems that the `libwebp-dev` package is also a required dependency

Comment: The `ln`-step is not necessary when you give the loader path when building. As Nmath, I had to install `libwebp-dev` and also `libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev`.

Comment: Finally, I had to symlink/move ´libpixbufloader-webp.so´ from `/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders` to `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders`, then run `sudo /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/gdk-pixbuf-query-loaders --update-cache` to make it work.

Comment: I was using gThumb before I used this answer and every time I opened a .wepb file with gThumb I got a black screen for 2-3 seconds and one time in five it also totally froze the computer at the black screen and turned off the monitor requiring a reboot to continue. Problem solved, now I can open .webp files in Image Viewer by default instead of in gThumb.

Answer (score 5):

### Ubuntu 22.04

You simply need to install `webp-pixbuf-loader` and make EOG the default program for `webp` extensions.

```
sudo apt install webp-pixbuf-loader
```

### Ubuntu 20.04

For previous versions of Ubuntu you can add `ppa:helkaluin/webp-pixbuf-loader` PPA and proceed similarly.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:helkaluin/webp-pixbuf-loader
sudo apt update
sudo apt install webp-pixbuf-loader
```

Comment: Great! Now if there was also one for .avif ...!

Answer (score 3):

I found this OMG! Ubuntu! article: [How to Add WebP Support to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2022/08/install-webp-image-support-ubuntu-22-04)

Just add the `ppa:helkaluin/webp-pixbuf-loader` PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:helkaluin/webp-pixbuf-loader
```

Then install `webp-pixbuf-loader`:

```
sudo apt install webp-pixbuf-loader
```

and you're done. Works for me on Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 0):

These dependent packages should be installed.

```
sudo apt install libwebp-dev libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev libgtk-3-dev meson build-essential
```

then, build and install like this.

```
git clone https://github.com/aruiz/webp-pixbuf-loader
cd webp-pixbuf-loader/
meson builddir -Dgdk_pixbuf_query_loaders_path=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/gdk-pixbuf-query-loaders
ninja -C builddir
sudo ninja -C builddir install
```